# Hangouts chat API returns 400 for create message of type actionResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api-client, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I trying to post messages using chat [python client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client). Request body should be of type https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages?hl=zh-cn#Message.

This is my sample code.

```
    def callback(message):
    logging.info('Received message: %s', message.data)

    event = json.loads(message.data)
    space_name = event['space']['name']

    # If the bot was removed, we don't need to return a response.
    if event['type'] == 'REMOVED_FROM_SPACE':
        logging.info('Bot removed rom space %s', space_name)
        return

    # response = format_response(event)
    response = {'actionResponse': {'type': 'REQUEST_CONFIG', 'url': 'https://google.com'}}
    
    # Send the asynchronous response back to Hangouts Chat
    chat.spaces().messages().create(
        parent=space_name,
        body=response).execute()
    message.ack()
```

I get this error

```
E2020-08-14 21:43:08,632 streaming_pull_manager.py:82] Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kasi/repos/hangouts-chat-samples/python/pub-sub-bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 77, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "bot.py", line 59, in callback
    chat.spaces().messages().create(
  File "/Users/kasi/repos/hangouts-chat-samples/python/pub-sub-bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kasi/repos/hangouts-chat-samples/python/pub-sub-bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 917, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/1YIkLgAAAAE/messages?alt=json returned "Message cannot be empty.">
```

If I add a text field to response, bot response message is exactly same as simple text reply. for below given response body.

```
        response = {
        'actionResponse': {
            'type': 'REQUEST_CONFIG',
            'url': 'https://google.com'
        },
        'text': 'This is a text',
        'thread': {'name': 'spaces/AAAAiu7EpR8/threads/4wRxupjMbbk'}
    }
```

I am getting this instead of a private message.

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

Comment: What if you try a sync instead of an asynch approach? https://developers.google.cn/hangouts/chat/how-tos/arch-guide

Comment: I tried sync using https://developers.google.cn/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python. I am getting the same error message `Message cannot be empty.`
This is the json payload I dumped from apps scripts logs viewer. `jsonPayload:{message:"{"actionResponse":{"type":"REQUEST_CONFIG","url":"https://google.com"}}"`.

Comment: I ssume that you use the asynchroneous approach with a service account and the synchroneous one without - as described in the [documentaiton](https://developers.google.cn/hangouts/chat/how-tos/arch-guide#endpoint_type)? When you respond asynchroneously, it is like [sending a spontaneous message into an existing thread](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop#asyncresponse), so you need to include the thread id. Did you try without `text` but with `actionResponse` AND `threadId`?

Comment: `{
    'thread': {
        'name': 'spaces/AAAAiu7EpR8/threads/4wRxupjMbbk'
    },
    'actionResponse': {
       'type': 'REQUEST_CONFIG',
         'url': 'https://google.com'
    }
}`

Comment: @ziganotschka I tried to include thread field as you mentioned but still getting same error. Tried with both service account and webhook.

Comment: What scopes are you using respectively for sync and async requests? Can you provide your full code including Chat aPI authenticaiton and some description about how you set the bot up?

Comment: Are deplyoing the bot in python as explained [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/hangouts-chat-samples/tree/master/python/auth-bot) or are you using a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks)?